# Error loading libQt3Support.so.4

Tags: software-installation, dependencies, qt, libraries, qt3

I am trying to install this software called [Vlab](http://algorithmicbotany.org/virtual_laboratory/). Its a Plant modelling software. I am following their [instruction](http://paste.ubuntu.com/9516287/) to install their software. After that if i run the command

> vlab-splash

which is supposed to start the application, it says

`raja@raja-XPS-8300:~$ vlab-splash
 vlab-splash: error while loading shared libraries: libQt3Support.so.4:  cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I have all the dependencies installed. I have qt4-sdk qt4 creator. Help me fix this. Thanks

Comment: How did you determine that you have all the dependencies installed? The `libQt3Support.so.4` library appears to be part of package `libqt4-qt3support`, which AFAIK is a dependency of the qt4 development packages (but not of the qt4 runtime framework)

Comment: I have libqt4-qt3support installed. Still it doesn't work.  I also have qt4-dev-tools, qt4-sdk installed. Hence I assumed dependencies should have been met.  Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

This might be because you have the 64-bit libqt4-qt3support libraries. Get the 32-bit libraries like so

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386
apt-get update
apt-get install libc6:i386 libqt4-qt3support:i386
```